# How to track no-sound area in a .wav file?

Tags: java, audio, mfc, wav

How to track sections without sounds in a wav file?

A small software that I want to develop is dividing a wav file, and it consider a no volume area as a dividing point.

How can a program know that volume of a wav file is low?
I'll use Java or MFC.

Answer (score 8):

I've had success with silence detection by calculating RMS of the signal. This is done in the following manner (assuming you have an array of audio samples):

```
    long sumOfSquares = 0;
    for (int i = startindex; i <= endindex; i++) {
        sumOfSquares = sumOfSquares + samples[i] * samples[i];
    }
    int numberOfSamples = endindex - startindex + 1;
    long rms = Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares / (numberOfSamples));
```

if rms is below a certain threshold, you can consider it being silent.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a wave file is basically a list of values, which represents a sound wave discretely divided with some rate (44100 Hz usually). Silence is basically when values are near 0. Just set some threshold value and look for continuous ( let's say 100ms length) regions where value is below that threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Simple silence detection is done by sequentially comparing sound chunks with some value (which is chosen depending on record quality).

Something like:

```
abs(track[position]) < 0.1
```

or

```
(track[position]) < 0.1) && (track[position]) > -0.1)
```

if we assume that chunk is [-1, 1] float.

It would work better if sound is normalized.