# How to cut silence in the end of a wav file using Java?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

How can I erase the silence (lower then the threshold) part of a wav file using Java?
Some say "pull samples out of the PCM data". How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808146/how-to-track-no-sound-area-in-a-wav-file + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786660/remove-the-first-5-of-a-second-from-wav-file

Comment: @javatar can you share your solution code? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be straight forward.  A wav is uncompressed so you can simply open it and process it using standard (binary) input streams.

For the actual audio processing, the Java Sound API will do the trick.  Check out http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html for full details.  Nice to play with.